# Converting only time to unixtimestamp in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, timestamp, hiveql, unix-timestamp

I have a column `eventtime` that only stores the time of day as string.  Eg:
`0445AM` - means `04:45 AM`.  I am using the below query to convert to UNIX timestamp.

```
select unix_timestamp(eventtime,'hhmmaa'),eventtime from data_raw limit 10;
```

This seems to work fine for test data.  I always thought unixtimestamp is a combination of date and time while here I only have the time.  My question is what date does it consider while executing the above function?  The timestamps seem to be quite small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unix timestamp is the bigint number of seconds from Unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC). The unix time stamp is a way to track time as a running total of seconds.

```
select unix_timestamp('0445AM','hhmmaa') as unixtimestamp
```

Returns

```
17100
```

And this is exactly 4hrs, 45min converted to seconds.

```
select 4*60*60 + 45*60
```

returns `17100`

And to convert it back use `from_unixtime`  function

```
select from_unixtime (17100,'hhmmaa')
```

returns:

```
0445AM
```

If you convert using format including date, you will see it assumes the date is `1970-01-01`

```
select from_unixtime (17100,'yyyy-MM-dd hhmmaa')
```

returns:

```
1970-01-01 0445AM
```

See Hive functions dosc [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF).

Also there is very useful site about [Unix timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/)

Comment: Thank you.  That's a clear explanation.  Am a newbie to Hive.  Never thought of converting it back providing the 'yyyy-MM-dd' option.